# /deep/ combinator in CSS is deprecated and will be removed in M63

Tags: html, css, angular

I updated my angular to 4.0.0 and chrome to to 62.0.3202.94 and I got this error:

> [Deprecation] /deep/ combinator in CSS is deprecated and will be removed in M63, around December 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4964279606312960 for more details.

And is refer to `clientWidth` or `clientHeight` in my code:

```
document.getElementById(this.ID).clientWidth;
```

or here:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'), 10);
```

Is this error misinterpreted by the browser? How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

`/deep/` being deprecated in any browser is entirely irrelevant to Angular.

Angular rewrites the selector so that it doesn't use `/deep/` or it's newer replacement `::ng-deep` when the application is loaded.

`/deep/` and `::ng-deep` are just hints for Angular to not include the unique class (like `_ngcontent-1`), Angular adds to each component host element, in the CSS selector.

See also https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: I think i got this. Thanks for explain.